# Squares inside the square with CSS

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-selectors

I am trying to have 4 little squares inside one big square. Those small squares need to be position at the bottom inside a big square, so far my code looks like this

```css
.date-grid button {
  position: relative;
  border: 0;
  width: 7.5ch;
  height: 7.5ch;
  background-color: #A1A100;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}

.smallHolder {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.small1 {
  border: 0;
  width: 2.5ch;
  height: 2.5ch;
  background-color: gray;
}

.small2 {
  width: 2.5ch;
  height: 2.5ch;
  background-color: red;
}

.small3 {
  border: 0;
  width: 2.5ch;
  height: 2.5ch;
  background-color: green;
}

.small4 {
  border: 0;
  width: 2.5ch;
  height: 2.5ch;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="date-grid">
  <button class="vrs22">
       <time>3</time>
    <div class="smallHolder">
      <div class="small1"></div>
      <div class="small2"></div>
      <div class="small3"></div>
      <div class="small4"></div>
    </div>   
   </button>
</div>
```

What I am trying to achieve is this:

[image]

Idea is to have this flexible so if I have 2 small squares, results should be like this:

[image]

Can anybody try to help me with this?

Comment: hmm - the small rectangles in your last image aren't squares. Should they be squares (they would take half of the big square's space)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be a solution. It uses your unaltered HTML, but with completely different CSS. Changing the `height` and `width` of the outer container will still result in 4 small squares, as long as width and height of the outer container are equal.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.date-grid {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #eee;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.vrs22 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: green;
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
}

time {
  display: block;
  height: 75%;
  font-size: 24px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.smallHolder {
  width: 100%;
  height: 25%;
  display: flex;
}

.smallHolder>div {
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.small1 {
  background: #fb0;
}

.small2 {
  background: #bf0;
}

.small3 {
  background: #f07;
}

.small4 {
  background: #ba0;
}
```

```html
<div class="date-grid">
  <button class="vrs22">
       <time>3</time>
    <div class="smallHolder">
      <div class="small1"></div>
      <div class="small2"></div>
      <div class="small3"></div>
      <div class="small4"></div>
    </div>   
   </button>
</div>
```

With different container size:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.date-grid {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: #eee;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.vrs22 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: green;
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
}

time {
  display: block;
  height: 75%;
  font-size: 24px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.smallHolder {
  width: 100%;
  height: 25%;
  display: flex;
}

.smallHolder>div {
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.small1 {
  background: #fb0;
}

.small2 {
  background: #bf0;
}

.small3 {
  background: #f07;
}

.small4 {
  background: #ba0;
}
```

```html
<div class="date-grid">
  <button class="vrs22">
       <time>3</time>
    <div class="smallHolder">
      <div class="small1"></div>
      <div class="small2"></div>
      <div class="small3"></div>
      <div class="small4"></div>
    </div>   
   </button>
</div>
```

And a variation with only two squares at the bottom:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.date-grid {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #eee;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.vrs22 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: green;
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
}

time {
  display: block;
  height: 50%;
  font-size: 24px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.smallHolder {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  display: flex;
}

.smallHolder>div {
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.small1 {
  background: #fb0;
}

.small2 {
  background: #bf0;
}
```

```html
<div class="date-grid">
  <button class="vrs22">
       <time>3</time>
    <div class="smallHolder">
      <div class="small1"></div>
      <div class="small2"></div>
    </div>   
   </button>
</div>
```